# VM Exception and revert when sending money to contract within truffle test

Tags: contract-development, truffle, unittesting

I am writing a simple truffle test to send money to my deployed contract:

```
const Test = artifacts.require("Test");

contract("Test", accounts => {
    it("Deposit", async () => {
        let instance = await Test.deployed();
        let raw = {
            "from": accounts[0],
            "to": Test.address,
            "value": web3.utils.toWei("10", "ether"),
            "chain": 3
        }
        console.log(raw)
        await web3.eth.sendTransaction(raw, (res, error) => {
            console.log("RESULT")
            console.log(res)
            console.log("ERROR")
            console.log(error)
        })
        balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(Test.address)
        assert.equal(balance, web3.utils.toWei("10", "ether"))
    })

    it("Withdraw", async () => {
        let instance = await Test.deployed();
        instance.testArbitrage({value: 100, from: accounts[0]})
    })
}
```

When I simply use truffle develop and in console and run this test code line by line, the transaction works properly, however when I try to run this test I get the following error.

```
Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
      at Object.ErrorResponse (C:\Users\bigba\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\lib\errors.js:28:1)
      at C:\Users\bigba\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\web3\node_modules\web3-core-requestmanager\lib\index.js:303:1
      at C:\Users\bigba\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\provider\wrapper.js:107:1
      at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\bigba\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\web3\node_modules\web3-providers-http\lib\index.js:98:1)
      at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\bigba\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:1)
      at XMLHttpRequest.exports.modules.996763.XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\bigba\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:208:1)
      at XMLHttpRequest.exports.modules.996763.XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (C:\Users\bigba\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:318:1)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bigba\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:289:47)
      at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
```

Additionally I tried sending the eth using the .send function:

```
instance.send(10, {from: accounts[0]})
```

But still ran into the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by creating a payable function in my smart contract and sending eth to that function instead of directly to the contract. Still not sure why I ran into this error in the testing environment but not in the truffle develop environment though.